# Подтормаживает slideToggle при большом количестве контента

Tags: jquery

Разрабатываю свой собственный проект, где на одной из страниц есть кнопка "Показать ещё", по которой отправляется ajax-запрос, подгружает данные, отправляет в шаблонизатор и вызывает функцию, вставляющую готовый DOM на страницу. Так вот, когда DOM-элементов на странице становится много(после нескольких кликов по "Показать ещё"), то slideToggle начинает подлагивать и довольно заметно. Чего я только не гуглил и единственное, что предлагают - унылую css3 анимацию. Есть ли какой-то способ заменить slideToggle, способный увеличить производительность многократно? Даже при большом количестве DOM`a?

Comment: ccs3 анимация может все делать, что и slideToggle. Точнее говоря, slideToggle использует CSS. Чтобы сделать анимации можно создать класс открытого вариант + transition

Comment: @Node_pro на примере показать можете?

Answer (score 1):

slideToggle, может тормозит при использовании таблиц. Может также работать некорректно при использовании таких css свойств как padding и margin.

Способ увеличить производительность - это заменить анимацию js и делать ее с помощью css. 
Пример:

```
  -webkit-transition: height ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: height ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: height ease-in-out .15s;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3uqba4w/

Comment: А как на счёт динамического контента? Если что, `transition` не сможет анимировать `height: 0` до `height: auto`. Ставить фиксированную высоту - костыль. Ставить `max-height` - костыль.